# SKParticle File In single view application? (Xcode and swift)

Tags: scenekit, skscene, particle-system

I have made a simple game in the single view application pain of Xcode. I want to have a particle file running in the background so the background looks like stars. can this be done in the single view application mode? if so how can it be implemented?

Answer (score 0):

Look at SCNScene's `background.contents`. Set it to a SpriteKit scene that renders your starfield. SCNMaterialProperty is the relevant class.